# Laravel 5.2: Catching internal exceptions for better debugging

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to use default authentication facades from Laravel 5 with my custom user table.  While there are some good references that show how this can be done, I spent almost two days identifying some trivial issues that caused authentication failure.

(For reference) The changes required were rather simple.

1. I updated 'providers' section in `config/auth.php` to indicate the model that represents my `Authenticatable` users.
2. Added following variables to my model

```
    protected $table = 'my_user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'my_user_id';
```

3. Updated `Auth/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`.  This is where I really got stuck.  Since I don't depend on email address for login, I wanted a way to use `username` for login.  There were no ways to figure this out unless you read `AutheticatesUsers` trait. All that required was the following line here.

`protected $username = 'username';`

The issue was that though I give correct `username` and `password`, I'll get the login page again or the home page (depending on where you redirect to) with guest privilege. There were no log messages indicating any problems in the login sequence. Reading the code, I figured that there are a number of exceptions raised in the validation code which invalidates the login sequence and show the login page again.

Is there a way to to override the `throw...Exception()` calls so that I know where and why the exception is raised.  I could have saved 2 days if there are some log messages before throwing the exception.  Currently I'm stuck with another similar problem and struggling due to lack of debugging information.